# How to read from Named Pipe latest data for a while and save that data to disc using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, save, named-pipes

So I have some server broadcasting live data onto Named Pipe -  `\\.\pipe\TestChannel` (from [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) for example). I want to read it from now some `N` seconds and save that readen data to `some.file`. How to do such thing using C# .Net3.5? (and BTW I wonder about if it is easier to do it from .net4) Could you please provide some simple code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`NamedPipeClientStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx) to open the pipe, and read in your data.  Just read in the data using standard Stream functions (just like a file), and reroute to the other file as needed.